# How to google programming syntax?

Tags: google-search

Suppose I'm working on some PHP code, but I'm not very good at PHP. I come across the line

```
  <nav class="<?= $this->class .....
```

I've never seen `<?=` before, so I want to know what it means. I type `php <?=` into Google. However this doesn't yield any actual results, except for the [PHP website](https://secure.php.net/).

I've tried googling for `php "<?="` as well, with no improvement.

I finally figured out what `<?=` actually means by googling `php opening tags`.

Is there any way to google *actual syntax* that delivers better results?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. Search systems are typically human-language oriented and use tokenization, which treats most punctuation and other symbols as token separators. Even within quotes. That's why there are specialized search engines for that. The good news is, you can use Google to find them ;)

Comment: Theres a search engine that specifically is used to search for code. I can't remember what the engine is called though. Should be easy to Google. But no, I don't think there's any way using Google directly.